# Merge single commit to master from other branch

Tags: git, merge, git-cherry-pick

Let's say I have 2 git branches: develop and master. Master branch contains sources for stable version of my my app and develop is for unstable and not fully tested code.

After merging master to develop, there were some commits, then one single commit that changes project settings to make possible to build my app with recent Android Studio 3.0 (not backward compatible). After this, some more commits that I don't want to merge to master yet.

Now I don't have Android Studio 2 installed, so I am unable to compile stable version of my app anymore.
My idea is to merge (cherrypick) single commit from develop branch to master, so I will able to compile it with Android Studio 3.0. I don't want to merge any commit pushed before or after the one that I'm interested in (Android studio version bump). I also don't want any conflicts later, ehen merging develop into master.

I'm not sure if git cherry pick is right thing in this case, can you provide some tips for me?

Comment: `cherry-pick` is exactly the right tool if your goal is to take a single commit from your `develop` branch.  You may want to rebase your `develop` branch afterwards (so that there is a linear history from `master` -> `develop`, which will making merging easier in the future).